# Why was this question closed when there are plenty of similar questions open?

Tags: discussion, closing, reopen

[What does 'game-training' got to do with an application that cheats in a game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115737/why-is-an-application-used-to-cheat-in-a-game-called-a-game-trainer)

This question seems legit to me, the poster, as there are plenty other questions about the origins of a certain gaming term. I'd like to know why it is treated differently from them.

Some users who deemed this question worthy of reopening cast their votes, but [three of the same users who initially cast their votes to close have voted again to leave it closed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/35727). I'd like an explanation from them, if it is possible.

Other questions similar to this one are [Why are bosses called 'bosses'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33359/why-are-bosses-called-bosses) and everything under: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bterminology%5D+%7Eorigin , https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bterminology%5D+%7Esource and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bterminology%5D+%7Ehistory

Comment: "Why do words mean things" isn't much of a question.

Comment: @MatthewRead At least it is on [english.se]. Still many of such questions are out there in the *open*. But really why is my question any different from those other questions? At first my thought was also "Hey, it's primarily a gaming site, maybe I should post on ELU", but then I found those other questions here, and my question should be interesting for gamers.

Comment: @MatthewRead - Tell that to the [terminology](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tag.

Comment: @Robotnik There is not a single open question in that tag so poorly expressed as this one.

Comment: @MatthewRead I am all open to suggestions. I want to make my question better. Not just because it may be required for reopening.

Comment: Change it to simply "What is the origin of the term 'game trainer'?" and nothing more and it may be accepted.  Your speculation is extremely confusing and detracts from the post as a question.  Or simply say you don't understand how anything is being "trained" and ask for the meaning of the term.  "Why" in particular is unanswerable -- people name things because they name things, nothing deeper really.

Comment: I can agree that the title could be a little better, though the question cannot be reopened through casting reopen votes now, as it has been voted to stay closed. So only a moderator intervention can help.

Comment: @user1306322 a closed question can be re-opened if 5 users vote to reopen it. No moderator intervention is required.

Comment: @Oak [This comment](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115737/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-game-trainer#comment155556_115737) gave me a different impression. I guess the ones who already voted for reopening can't do that again, and those who voted to leave closed also can't do that anymore?

Comment: @user1306322 The question just [got removed from the reopen review queue](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7110/4797). People can still vote to reopen it. See [this meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7110/4797) for more info.

Comment: @MatthewRead "*Change it to simply "What is the origin of the term 'game trainer'?" and nothing more and it may be accepted. Your speculation is extremely confusing and detracts from the post as a question.*" That's what OP's question originally sounded like.([See the revision history here.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/115737/revisions)) The OP added the "speculations" because of comments by some of the close voters (now deleted) that the question has nothing to do with gaming and is better suited to EL&U. He's getting conflicting information on what counts as on/off-topic in Arqade.

Comment: @galacticninja I don't think those comments were looking for those ideas in particular to be added to the question.  I think the original question could still have been simplified and altered away from the "why" a bit.  The current version is excellent!

Comment: @user1306322; I do not feel it would be possible to provide an **authoritative answer** on this question, and that regardless of what form it takes it will ultimately result in speculation, which is why I have voted to re-close this question. It isn't off topic though, it's just not constructive.

Comment: @kalina a lot of questions I ask I have the same feeling about, but what if there's somebody who actually knows the answer? That's why I ask them anyway. And I don't think that makes it less constructive, maybe not so easy to find an answer to.

Comment: @user1306322 Oh, I'm not going to have a go over the question being asked, don't get me wrong. However, any answer that your question attracts will not cite any references or sources, and will solicit debate - which is pretty much the exact wording of the "close as not constructive" text.

Comment: @kalina we can't be so sure about that, can we? I've seen some similar questions answered with a citing of the first mentioning of the term usage, so.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Questions which are closed as something other than a duplicate are eventually all deleted. Closing isn't intended to be a permanent state, but a temporary one. All (non-dup) closed questions are either eventually fixed and re-opened or deleted.

Comment: @Wipqozn I've seen many times people say that closing and reopening is the natural order of things for questions on SE.

Comment: Upvotes on a closed question do not automatically mean the question should stick around.  If it's closed as anything other than a dupe, it should eventually get deleted.  It's just part of site cleanup.

Answer (score 3):

We don't usually like *objective* questions that ask why things are the way they are or what the origin of something is as those questions often either fall in the realm of game design (regrettably off topic) or are quite challenging to answer authoritatively without resorting to guesstimations, like I just have in the comments.

There's no easy fix for this. This honestly sounds like the subject for a short research paper rather than a question for a site of enthusiasts. This wouldn't make the question bad per se if it wasn't for its being a honey pot for bad answers that may sound right but aren't.

Comment: Making the question subjective obviously doesn't work because it'd then become a poll. "Why do you think..."

Comment: So I guess the times have changed and such questions no longer fit this site, then?

Comment: @user1306322 There's no harm in _trying_ and I wouldn't quite say there's a _ban_ on those questions, but the risk of facing community rejection for those is high.

Comment: @user1306322/badp What if the question was changed from a speculation on the origins of the term, to a question that simply asked what it meant in terms of cheating, as the body implies?

Comment: @Robotnik I don't really care any more, because I got my answer. If you think it's worth changing it so that it goes visible again for other users who might find that interesting, go ahead.

Comment: @user1306322 - done